# How to display URI of dynamic pages instead of just example.com

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, uri

I have website made using HTML5, CSS, PHP and jQuery (with AJAX).

URL, when I visit home page is like http://www.example.com, which is fine. But when I visit a different page (which loads using AJAX with help of jQuery), URL is still same (so http://www.example.com).

It's not even displaying how it normally would (example.com/index.php or example.com/partials/somethingelse.php).

I would like to display home page as it is now (example.com) and other sites that are inside folder partials like example.com/somethingelse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: You can use some routing helper like [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

Comment: Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history